# Android populate edittext value using bytes?

Tags: android

Is it possible to populate EditText value using bytes in android. I want to display a few number of images in an Edittext. Is there any way i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  How are you planning to display images in EditText?  `EditText` is for displaying and editing text.  You can set text into `EditText` from a `String` or any other `CharacterSequence`.  If you have your data in a byte array, then you can create a String from bytes and set it into the `EditText` like so:

```
EditText et = this.findViewById(R.id.EditText);
byte[] data = ...;
et.setText(new String(data));
```

Yet, I fail to see where images come into play.  If you explain better what you are trying to achieve, I will update my answer accordingly.